# Tag friends in uploaded image

Tags: facebook

I have the code that upload image and and tags users in wall

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
                $args = array('message' => 'by http://www.lookmywebpage.com/api');
                copy('http://demo.lookmywebpage.com/facebook-upload-photos/penguin.png', 'tmp/file.jpeg');
                $args['image'] = '@' . realpath('tmp/file.jpeg');
                $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
                unlink('tmp/file.jpeg');
                //assigning users to tag and cordinates
                $argstag = array('to' => $user);
                $argstag['x'] = 40;
                $argstag['y'] = 40;
                $datatag = $facebook->api('/' . $data['id'] . '/tags', 'post', $argstag);
                echo 'Success! Check your facebook wall now';
```

But i need to Tag 20 friends on it ..some one help me please

Comment: You can refer this link. It will be helpful for you.[Simple image tagging page like facebook image tag][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833253/simple-image-tagging-page-like-facebook-image-tag/23129551#23129551

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.
If you already have friend_id, just replace it with the `"$user"` variable and do a for loop