# Simple image tagging page like facebook image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, image

```
<html>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>IMAGE TAGGING</title>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="container" style="width:800px">
            <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Tag Your Friends</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; height:450px; width:800px; float:left;">
                <div style="color:#0000FF">
                    <center>
                        <!--<img border="0" src="clock.jpg" onclick="myFunction(e)" width="800px" height="450">-->
                        <div id="pointer_div" onclick="myFunction(event)" style = "background-image:url('clock.jpg');width:800px;height:450px;">
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="planetmap">

            </div>
            <div id='form_panel'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='label' id='label'>Title</div><div class='field' id='field'><input type='text' id='title' name='title' /></div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='label'></div>
                    <div class='field'>
                        <input type='button' value='Add Tag' onclick='addTag()' id='addTag'/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="footer" style="background-color:#ADFF85; clear:both; text-align:center;" >
                <h3>Your Friends Here: </h3><div id="demo" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script>
    var pos_x;
    var pos_y;
        function myFunction(e)  // called when click on image to create span and textbox
        {
            $("#title").val("");
            pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
            pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
            x_pos = event.pageX;
            y_pos = event.pageY;
            x_pos = x_pos - 50;
            y_pos = y_pos - 50;
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.id = "someID";
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            document.getElementById('someID').style.width='100px';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.height='100px';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.background='transparent';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.border='thick solid #0000FF';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.position = "absolute";
            x = document.getElementById('someID').style.left=x_pos+'px';
            y = document.getElementById('someID').style.top=y_pos+'px';
            form(x_pos,y_pos);
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        jQuery(window).load(function(){
              jQuery("#form_panel").hide();

             $('#addTag').on('click',function (e) {  //creates span dynamically
                $('#demo').append('<span class="tags" id="'+$('#title').val()+'" data-y="'+'this.pos_y'+'" data-x="'+'this.pos_x'+'">'+$('#title').val()+', </span>');
                console.log("#addTag'");
                console.log(pos_x);console.log(this.data-y);

            });


            jQuery(".tags").live("mouseover",function(){
                // $(this).find(".tagged_box").css("background-color","yellow");
                console.log("mouseover");console.log(this.id);console.log(pos_y);
                console.log(this.data-y);  // here i have stuck
                //over();


            });
        })

        function over(){

            console.log("demo over");

        }

        function form(x_pos,y_pos){   // to create textbox, call from myFunction()
            jQuery("#someID").show();
            var ele = document.getElementById('form_panel');
            x_pos = x_pos - 25;
            y_pos = y_pos - 80;
            document.body.appendChild(form_panel);
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.width='180px';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.height='70px';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.background='#eee';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.position = "absolute";
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.left=x_pos+'px';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.top=y_pos+'px';
            //console.log("form is showing in form()");
            jQuery("#form_panel").show();
        }

        function addTag(){

            var text = document.getElementById('title').value; //value of text box 
            //console.log(text);
            var demoid = document.getElementById('demo'); //html of #demo
            //console.log(demoid);
            jQuery("#form_panel").hide();
            jQuery("#someID").hide();
            //console.log("in addTag");

        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to make a simple image tagging page like facebook image tag functionality, I am able to tag names but further I want to add one functionality. Whenever I will hover on names which are tagged, it should show me where it is tagged on image.

Comment: Make a fiddle. Also without looking at your code, I think css visibility is your friend. On hover make it visible and hover out, change the visibility to hidden.

Comment: @AamirAfridi I have stuck at how to save or use coordinates of particular tagged name without database. Further it will be possible to change the visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have made for image tagging. You can add tag and delete tag. And save those tagged name in text file so that on refresh tagged name should not disappear.

```
<html>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>IMAGE TAGGING</title>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="container" style="width:800px">
            <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Tag Your Friends</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; height:450px; width:800px; float:left;">
                <div style="color:gray">
                    <center>
                        <div id="pointer_div" class="pointer_div" onclick="myFunction(event)" style = "background-image:url('abstract-hd-wallpaper-24.jpg');width:800px;height:450px;">
              <?php
              $filetxt = 'data/data.txt';
              if(file_exists($filetxt)) 
              {
                $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

                $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
                $length=sizeof($arr_data);
                $i=0;
                while ( $i< $length) 
                {

                  ?>  
                  <div class="store" id="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['youname'];?>" data-y="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['x'];?>" data-x="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['y'];?>" style="top:<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['x'];?>px; left:<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['y'];?>px; position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; border:3px solid gray" ><?php echo $arr_data[$i]['youname'];?></div>
                  <?php 
                  $i++;
                }

              }
              else echo 'The file '. $filetxt .' not exists';
            ?>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="planetmap">
      </div>
            <div id='form_panel'>
          <div class='row'>
            <form  id ="saveform">
              <div class='label' id='label'>Title</div>
              <div class='field' id='field'>
                <input type='text' id='title' name='title' />
              </div>
              <input type='button' value='Add Tag' id='addTag'/><!-- <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='cancel()' id='cancel'/> -->
              </form>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "overshow" id = "overshow" style="color:red;"></div>
        <div id="footer" style="background-color:#ADFF85; clear:both; text-align:center;" >
            <h3>Your Friends Here: </h3>
        <div id="demo" >
            <?php
              $filetxt = 'data/data.txt';
              if(file_exists($filetxt)) 
              {
                $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

                $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
                $length=sizeof($arr_data);
                $i=0;
                while ( $i< $length) 
                {

                  ?>  
                  <span class="tags" id="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['youname'];?>" data-y="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['x'];?>" data-x="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['y'];?>" ><?php echo $arr_data[$i]['youname'];?><span class="del" id="<?php echo $arr_data[$i]['youname'];?>" style="color:red">X</span></span>
                  <?php 
                  $i++;
                }

              }
              else echo 'The file '. $filetxt .' not exists';
            ?>
        </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </center>



    <script>
    var x_pos;
    var y_pos;
        function myFunction(e)  // called when click on image to create span and textbox
        {
            $("#title").val("");
            pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
            pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
            x_pos = event.pageX;
            y_pos = event.pageY;
            x_pos = x_pos - 50;
            y_pos = y_pos - 50;
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.id = "someID";
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            document.getElementById('someID').style.width='100px';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.height='100px';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.background='transparent';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.border='thick solid #0000FF';
            document.getElementById('someID').style.position = "absolute";
            x = document.getElementById('someID').style.left=x_pos+'px';
            y = document.getElementById('someID').style.top=y_pos+'px';
            form(x_pos,y_pos);
        }
    </script>

    <script>
  var ids;
  var idss;
  var clas;
        $(window).load(function(){
            $("#form_panel").hide();
      $(".store").hide();
          var del_div = '<span class="del" id="del">DEL &nbsp</span>'
          var close_div = '<span class="cls" id="cls"> CLOSE</span>'
          $(".overshow").hide();
      console.log("form panel");


          $('#addTag').on('click',function (e) {  //creates span dynamically,called when clicked on addtag button
                var append_string = '<span class="tags" id="'+$('#title').val()+'" data-y="'+y_pos+'" data-x="'+x_pos+'">'+$('#title').val()+' <span class="del" id="'+$('#title').val()+'" style="color:red">X</span></span>'
                $('#demo').append(append_string);
          var store_div = '<div class="store" id="'+$('#title').val()+'" data-y="'+y_pos+'" data-x="'+x_pos+'" style="top:'+y_pos+'px; left:'+x_pos+'px; position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; border:3px solid gray">'+$('#title').val()+'</div>'
          $('#pointer_div').append(store_div);

          $('.store').hide('slow');
          console.log("store_div");
          $("#form_panel").hide('slow');
          $("#someID").hide('slow');
          var text = $('#title').val();
          var data_y = y_pos;
          var data_x = x_pos;
          console.log("ajax is ahead");

          $.ajax({                      // passing data to save in textfile
             type: "POST", // post or get
             url: 'save.php',
             data: 'text='+text+'&x='+data_y+'&y='+data_x,
             // dataType: "json",
             success: function(e)
             { 
               // alert(e);
             }
        });

            });


      jQuery(".tags").live('click',function(){ //to show a tagged pose
        ids = $(this).attr('id');
        idss=ids;
        console.log(ids);
        var x_cord = $(this).attr('data-x');
        var y_cord = $(this).attr('data-y');

        $('#overshow').show('fast'); //.delay(1000).hide('slow');
      });

      jQuery(".tags").live('mouseenter',function(){ //tag name mouseenter
          var idss = $(this).attr('id');
          ids=idss;
          console.log(idss);
          var x_cord = $(this).attr('data-x');
          var y_cord = $(this).attr('data-y');
              $("#overshow").css({top: y_cord, left: x_cord, width:'100px', height:'100px', position:'absolute',border:'3px solid gray'});
              $('#overshow').show('slow'); //.delay(1000).hide('slow');

        }); 
        jQuery(".tags").live('mouseleave',function(){
          $('#overshow').hide();
          // $('#overshow').show('slow').delay(1000).hide('slow');
        });

      jQuery(".cls").live('click',function(){ //to close a overshow of tag
        //alert("close");
        $('.overshow').hide();
      });

      jQuery(".del").live('click',function(){ //to delete a tag
        var idd=ids;
        $('.overshow').hide();
        $("#"+idss).remove();
        $("#"+idss).remove();
        $("#"+ids).remove();
        $("#"+ids).remove();
        $('.overshow').hide();

        var data_y = y_pos;
        var data_x = x_pos;

        $.ajax({ // passing data to delete from textfile
         type: "POST",  // post or get
         url: 'save.php',
         data: 'text1='+ids+'&x1='+data_y+'&y1='+data_x,
         // dataType: "json",
         success: function(e)
         { 
           // alert(e);
         }
        });

      });


      jQuery(".pointer_div").live('mouseenter',function(){ //image mouseenter
        console.log("mouseenter on image");
        $('.store').show();

      }); 

      jQuery(".pointer_div").live('mouseleave',function(){
        // console.log("mouseleave");
        $('.store').hide();
        $('.overshow').hide();

      });

      })

        function over(){

            console.log("demo over");

        }

        function form(x_pos,y_pos){   // to create textbox, call from myFunction()
            jQuery("#someID").show('slow');
        var ele = document.getElementById('form_panel');
            x_pos = x_pos - 25;
            y_pos = y_pos - 80;
            document.body.appendChild(form_panel);
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.width='180px';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.height='70px';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.background='#eee';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.position = "absolute";
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.left=x_pos+'px';
            document.getElementById('form_panel').style.top=y_pos+'px';
            //console.log("form is showing in form()");
            jQuery("#form_panel").show('slow');
        }

    function addTag(){

            var text = document.getElementById('title').value; //value of text box 
            console.log(text);
            var demoid = document.getElementById('demo'); //html of #demo
            //console.log(demoid);
            jQuery("#form_panel").hide('slow');
            jQuery("#someID").hide('slow');
    }

    function cancel(){

        $("#form_panel").hide('slow');
        $("#someID").hide('slow');
    }


    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The further code for saving tagged names in text file and get tagged names from that text file on refresh.

```
<?php
//refer : http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/add-form-data-text-file-json-format_t
$filetxt = 'data/data.txt';

// check if all form data are submited, else output error message
if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
  // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
  if(empty($_POST['text'])) {
    echo 'All fields are required';
  }
  else {
    // gets and adds form data into an array
    $formdata = array(
      'youname'=> $_POST['text'],
      'x'=> $_POST['x'],
      'y'=> $_POST['y'],
    );

    // path and name of the file
    $filetxt = 'data/data.txt';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
      echo $arr_data;
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $formdata;

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "formdata.txt" (in "dirdata" folder)
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents('data/data.txt', $jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
    else echo 'Unable to save data in "data/data.txt"';
  }
}
else {

  $filetxt = 'data/data.txt';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data
    echo $text1 = $_POST['text1'];

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

      foreach ( $arr_data as $k => $abc ) {
        // print_r($abc['youname']);
        if ( $abc['youname'] != $text1 ) {

            $xyz[]=$abc;
        }

      }

      print_r($xyz);

      $jsondata = json_encode($xyz, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      if(file_put_contents('data/data.txt', $jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
      else echo 'Unable to save data in "data/data.txt"';
    }
}
?>
```