# How to apply jquery / javascript Photo tag code in Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

We are working on adding Photo tagging feature in Odoo 10 custom module. 
We have created code in Odoo to upload an image in DB.

```
class PhotoMaster(models.Model):
    _name = 'photo.master'
    _rec_name = 'name'

    name = fields.Char('Photo ID')
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('name_uniq', 'unique (name)', "Photo Name already exists !"),
    ]
    photo = fields.Binary('Upload Photo')
```

**view.xml file is as below to show photo stored in DB.**

```
<group>
   <field name="name"/>
   <field  colspan="5" height="100%" width="100%" filename="name" name="photo" widget="image" id="photo"/>
</group>
```

**How can we apply below jquery / javascript code in Odoo 10?**

[Simple image tagging page like facebook image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833253/simple-image-tagging-page-like-facebook-image-tag)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are just needing to know how to add a custom Javascript file to be accessible to Odoo. It requires two steps.

1. Add your Javascript file(s) in `your_module/static/src/js`
2. Add XML to notify Odoo that those files exist

   ```
   <!-- Adds all assets in Odoo -->
   <template id="assets_backend" name="your_module assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
       <xpath expr="." position="inside">
           <!--These links will be called when loading your Odoo -->
           <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module/static/src/js/javascriptfile.js"></script>
       </xpath>
   </template>
   ```

[Further details from Yenthe's blog](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/adding-static-resources-css-and-javascript-to-odoo)